# C# class property {get; set;}

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any difference between:

```
public class user
{       
    public string Name { get; set; }  
}
```

And:

```
public class user
{       
    public string Name;  
}
```

???
Thank you

Comment: The difference is get-set. With them, they are properties, without them, fields. In Your example get-set don't do much, but you can use them.

Comment: in this case there is no difference between field and property really. but properties gives you ability to modify almost everything.

Comment: Who upvoted this one? Seriously?

Comment: There are subtle differences, but those differences are completely swamped by the "elephant in the room" problem with both. Both are bad practice as they offer no encapsulation of data and expose `Name` as publicly mutable. Please read http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/26/CodeSmellAutomaticProperty/ to understand why you should avoid both.

Answer (score 1):

First one is a property, second is a field.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx